# javascript: launch new window, redirect existing one, set focus in new window - how to?

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I'm having a problem trying to get this to work.  Here's my situation:

- using SAP Portal I'm launching an html page with the code below

- the html page needs to launch a brand new window

- the existing html page then needs to redirect itself back to the main portal page

- the newly launched window then needs to be brought to the forefront (set focus)

The issue is that when the portal reloads after being redirected it takes focus.  I also don't have access to the code of the application that I've launched in the new window so can't do anything there.

Here is the code I'm trying to use.  I've also tried to use a setTimeout() as well but it doesn't work.

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.open('https://passwordresetprogram','_blank');   
            window.top.location.href="http://originalurl";
        </script>
        <title>Password Reset</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

when I tried the commands in console

```
window.open('https://passwordresetprogram','_blank');   
window.top.location.href="http://originalurl";
```

it works as you mentioned

- the html page needs to launch a brand new window
- the existing html page then needs to redirect itself back to the main portal page
- the newly launched window then needs to be brought to the forefront (set focus)

and

to access the code of the application launched in new window, try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var popUp="";
    function OpenNew(passedURL){
        popUp = window.open('https://passwordresetprogram','_blank');
        popUp.document.getElementById("<some_selecior>").<some_attribute>=<some_code>;
    }
    </script>
```